# Generic service with multiple values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

Have multiple services, that provide very similar functionality but with some differences:

- `event-type1`, (event-type2 for second service etc.)
- `MODEL_A`, (MODEL_B for second service etc.),
- `URL_PART_A`, (URL_PART_B for second service etc.),

```
@Injectable()
export Type1Service extends Socket {
  type1Update$ = this.fromEvent<MODEL_A>('event-type1');

  constructor() {
    super({ url: `${environment.url}/${URL_PART_A}` });
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Type2Service extends Socket {
  type2Update$ = this.fromEvent<MODEL_B>('event-type2');

  constructor() {
    super({ url: `${environment.url}/${URL_PART_B}` });
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Type3Service extends Socket {
  type3Update$ = this.fromEvent<MODEL_C>('event-type3');

  constructor() {
    super({ url: `${environment.url}/${URL_PART_C}` });
  }
 }
```

I would like to use generic pattern service by @Inject decorator in components. I tried by export class `SocketService<T>`, but have the problem with multiple arguments.

Comment: 'I would like to use generic pattern service by @Inject decorator in components.' Please explain what you mean with an example.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton  Maybe I wrote it incorrectly. But I meant a generic service, where we put it by factory in the module, and the arguments can be injected via ```@Inject``` decorator. But the main question/problem is creating generic service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no just injecting a generic service directly that returns a different instance based on the generic parameter.  So here are a couple of choices - use injection service <strike>or create your own service provider</strike>.  *(After writing a custom service provider answer, the injection tokens just seem so much dead simpler that I removed it.)*

### Using Injection Tokens

```
/* Service */
export class TypeService<T> extends Socket {
  type1Update$ = this.fromEvent<T>(this.eventType);

  constructor(urlPart: string, private eventType: string) {
    super({ url: `${environment.url}/${urlPart}` });
  }
}

/* InjectionTokens - They can live anywhere. */
export const ModelATypeServiceToken = new InjectionToken<TypeService<ModelA>>(
  'TypeService for ModelA', 
  { factory: () => new TypeService('urlPartA', 'eventType1'), providedIn: 'root' });
export const ModelBTypeServiceToken = new InjectionToken<TypeService<ModelB>>(
  'TypeService for ModelB', 
  { factory: () => new TypeService('urlPartB', 'eventType2'), providedIn: 'root' });


/* Component */
constructor (@Inject(ModelATypeServiceToken) private typeASvc: TypeService<ModelA>) {}
```

In the above example, the **TypeService** is just a simple generic service with *urlPart* and *eventType* as a constructor parameters.  Injection tokens are created with default factories, that create unique instances of the *TypeService* per model type.

While it's not a simple as injecting a Generic service directly like you'd do in C#, it's not so bad to define a token per model.  How many models do you have in your application that would require engineering something more complex?

Comment: type1Update$ = this.fromEvent<T>('event-type1'); The argument here also needs to be generic right? You miss it?

Comment: Thanks @j1s.  That was missing.  Even though the answer was already accepted, I added it.

Comment: @DanielGimenez Thank you! There is any possibility to add State<Type> to constructor? When I tried to add it in factory: (store$: State<type) => new TypeService... it cause the bug.

Comment: So the factory method takes no parameters, but that's okay because you can use the **inject** function to inject the service.  Just note that you'll need injection tokens for each each type for State, `factory: () => new TypeService(inject(StateToken), 'url', 'eventType')`